# Is vSphere 5 compatible with an OpenIndiana/Napp-it iSCSI datastore?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, iscsi

My hostd.log file on vSphere 5 says that partedUtil is timing out while trying to write the partition table on an iSCSI target being served from OpenIndiana/napp-it.

I read that sized over 2TB give problems, so I sized the volume to 500GB.

I tried mounting the target in Ubuntu 11.04 with open-iscsi and it worked, so this seems to be an issue with the vSphere implementation of iSCSI or not?

Comment: Is there an actual question in there somewhere?

Comment: Please post the actual error message from the ESXi log.

Answer (score 3):

iSCSI is a standard protocol, and ESXi 5 is standard a iSCSI initiator, so it *should* be compatible with any iSCSI target; there really is not such a thing as a "compatible iSCSI target".

If we are instead talking about *supported* iSCSI targets, then you should have a look at the VMware HCL: http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=san. Anything that's not there *should* work, but it's not *guaranteed* to, and may require some tweaking or even not work at all.

Answer (score 2):

there are considerations with VMware iSCSI.  Take [openfiler/IET for example](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1026596).